# How to use fade-in text/image on page is loaded

Tags: html, css, animation, fadein, onload

I'm building a small website and would like to get the text (and an image when I add one) to **fade in** when someone accesses the website?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
      body {
          background-color: lightgrey;
      }
      ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
      }
      li {
          float: left;
      }
      li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
      }
      .active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
      }
  </style>
  <style>
      p.one {
          border: 1px lightgrey;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          padding-top: 50px;
          padding-right: 30px;
          padding-bottom: 40px;
          padding-left: 0px;
      }
      IMG.displayed {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Our Routes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img class="displayed" src="E:\Users\PC\Documents\Image" alt="...">
  <h1 align="center"> HOME </h1>
  <p class="one" , align="center"> Text Goes here
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alright, just a minute and I'll have an example for you. You've not used CSS3 Animations before? Check this quickly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: @StefanoSaitta Didn't see that thanks for the headsup, yeah pretty new to it! thanks for the link

Comment: @Joel That's great thankyou! No never used them, I'll look now

Comment: this comment might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602395/how-to-use-fade-in-on-page-load-up-html/52638510#52638510

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/GorVRL  [your site w/ fade and motion]
http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/BjpXRo  [example of the following instructions]

Here's an example. The HTML requires a div to be wrapped around the whole of the body content if you want it to fade in all at once. Look for this:

```
<div class="wrapper fade-in">
```

There's a lot of stuff you can do with CSS, I've been using it for years and I still learn something new every once in a while.

All the animation commands will appear in your CSS like so:

```
@keyframes fadeIn
  to { 
     opacity: 1; }
```

Then your divs are going to have a class that calls the animation (@keyframes):

```
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn 1.0s ease forwards;
  [other div properties can be included here]
}
```

The HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="fade-in">
[content]
</div>
```

Finally, you'll need to make sure you include the vendor codes to make it compatible with all browsers [which adds a fair amount of code, which is why jQuery can be a better option for this stuff]:

```
@keyframes fadeIn{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

The vendor codes will have to be duplicated again in your div class in the CSS:

```
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 5s;
}
```

The effect can be achieved with jQuery much quicker, as you can see in one of the other answers here.

---

After you've learned to do it by hand, I suggest playing around with this CSS3 animation generator if you want to save a bit of time:
http://cssanimate.com/

Just make sure you understand it first though.

Lastly, this is an example of jQuery performing similar functions (though using SVGs instead of divs this time, same process though):
http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/YwpBaQ

Comment: Thankyou! will give a go now!

Comment: No problem - I made an edit here around the time you commented, so just refresh it if you haven't seen the complete post because I clarified a little better.

Comment: yes makes more sense now! managed to get it working great :) What do I change by the way if I want to change the speed of the animation? is it animation frames 1s? So change if I change it to 2 it will be 2 seconds?

Comment: Exactly, that is the duration of the animation - you can also delay the animations for lengths of time, which you may want to do to achieve a staggered effect for multiple pieces of content fading in in sequence.

Comment: Awesome, going to playing round with this for ages, thanks again!

Comment: OK, check out the generator in the link I posted up there, it's pretty fun to see the results and be able to adjust them immediately to your liking. Here is an example of the animation delay being used (just press "View Compiled" at the top of the HTML/CSS boxes to see it in regular code you'll be familiar with): http://codepen.io/tnakatani/pen/AgexE

Answer (score 0):

You can fade in elements when the document loads by loading the page with the elements hidden (opacity : 0;) in CSS. Then on document ready you can remove the class, so long as it has a transition for that css property—you'll have an effect.

**CSS**

```
div {
    transition: opacity 2s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, I'll give that a try :)

Comment: what does a screenreader do with this method? will blind people be able to read the content?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what element you have but you can do a few things.

If you are using javascript, or jquery you can make an element fade in easily.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myItemClass').fadeIn();
});
```

You can also do it with just CSS

CSS:

```
/* The animation code */
@keyframes example {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

.myClass {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple don't need even jqyery, pure CSS and pure Javascript.

**CSS**

```
body {
opacity:0;
transition: 300ms opacity;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function pageLoaded() {
        document.querySelector("body").style.opacity = 1;
}
window.onload = pageLoaded;
```